# Function to return function of product of vector elements

Tags: r, vectorization

For a given vector of nodes, e.g., nodes = 1:5
I would like the function `prod_x` to return a function in x of the form
`f(x) = (x−1) * (x−2) * (x−3) * (x−4) * (x−5)`

```r
prod_x <- function(nodes){
    out <- prod(x - nodes)
    return(out)
}
```

I tried writing a `reprex` of what I expect below, but it does not work as intended.

Test out the function on a sample set of node values `1:5`

```r
NODES <- 1:5
z <- prod_x(nodes = NODES)
#> Error in prod_x(nodes = NODES): object 'x' not found
```

Expect this to return a function but returns 0 value

```r
z 
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'z' not found
```

`z(0)` Should produce -120, i.e. -factorial(5) in this case.

That is, `z(0) = (0 - 1)*(0 - 2)*(0 - 3)*(0 - 4)*(0 - 5)`

```r
z(0)
#> Error in z(0): could not find function "z"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As it can be seen the above approach does not work as intended. Could anyone explain how to make it work, and in a vectorized manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are not returning a function. In order to create a new function, you should see the `function` keyword. That's where you define the parameters as well. It should look like

```
prod_x <- function(nodes){
  function(x) {
    prod(x - nodes)
  }
}
```

This will work fine for one `x` but `prod()` will collapse multiple values of `x` into one result. If you want your function to be vectorized over `x`, then you could also add

```
prod_x <- function(nodes){
  Vectorize(function(x) {
    prod(x - nodes)
  })
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic - just what I was looking for! I realize now that I should have explicitly called `function` again inside the main function. Appreciate the alternative vectorized solution over `x`. For my understanding, the second is typically preferable to the non-vectorized version right? In the sense that it generalizes to arguments for x more than length 1?